# Github merging API returns 404 Not Found

Tags: github, github-api

I'm attempting to use the github api to merge a commit into a feature branch for an enterprise repository and am getting 404 Not Found which api docs say is either because the base branch or head provided in the POST request do not exist.

[github merge api docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#merging)

Things I've checked:

1. My api token has full repo access
2. The base branch has been pushed to origin
3. I can successfully merge the commit locally by running `git merge {hash}`
4. I'm able to successfully use the api for some other actions such as creating pull requests or comparing commits

---

Other things to note that may or may not be relevant. It's hard to tell since the 404 Not Found message is not that helpful.

- This base branch is set up to do fast-forwards of master branch commits so there will effectively never be merge commits to this branch, only fast-forwards.
- I was successfully able to create a pull request via the api on the same base branch as my attempts at merging, which indicates the base branch isn't the problem.
- Instead of using a commit hash for the head parameter I used `'master'` since the docs say you can alternatively use a branch name instead of a hash. But that didn't work-- same 404

There are other methods of doing fast forwards with the github api such as updating refs but I haven't gotten these to work either.

Comment: Testing this out on my personal repo it appears that the merge api will not do a fast-forward even if the history of the base branch doesn't diverge from the merged branch, so it's not the equivalent of doing `git merge`. But I'm still unsure why this api call won't work on my enterprise repo, as all things appear to be the same.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. If you have found solution could you please share?